# CakePHP Save for each checked item of separate model

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-1.3

I'm having some trouble saving multiple entries in CakePHP. I'm not sure whether `saveAll()` will do the trick as I'm trying to save an entry for each item checked from a join table which joins two separate tables to the one being saved to.

---

I have the following tables: `Samples`, `Results` and a join table called `SampleTypeTests` (joins two separate tables - SampleTypes & Tests).

Each Sample has an FK `sample_type_id`
Each Result has the FK `sample_id`, `sample_type_test_id`

I have an Add view for Results which lists all `SampleTypeTests` for a `Samples.sample_type_id`

My Add view form looks like this at the moment:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Result');
echo '<fieldset>';

    echo '<legend>Choose Analysis</legend>';

    echo $this->Form->input('sample_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value' => $this->passedArgs['0']));

    echo $this->Form->input('sample_type_test_id',array(
        'label' => __('Tests',true),
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $sampleTypeTests,
        'selected' => $html->value('Result.sample_type_test_id'),
        'hiddenField' => false
    )); 

echo '</fieldset>';

echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true)); ?>
```

The saving part is where I'm having the biggest headache. I need a `Results` entry created for each `SampleTypeTests` checked and that `SampleTypeTest.id` to be added to the FK `Results.sample_type_tests_id`.

I have tried to adapt the following to my needs http://mrphp.com.au/code/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp#habtm_checkbox

Here is what I got:

```
function add() {

    if ($this->Result->saveAll($this->data['Result'])) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('All required tests have been saved', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
    }

// Everything else
}
```

This hasn't worked. The above may be wrong. It is more to demonstrate what I've attempted. I'm getting very lost in it all and I need some help. Do I need to use `saveAll`? Do I need to nest the `save`? Have I made it far more complicated than it needs to be?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed the above form outputs the array as

```
Array (
[Result] => Array
    (
        [sample_id] => 21
        [sample_type_test_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 24
                [2] => 16
                [3] => 71
            )

    )
)
```

When what it should produce is:

```
Array
(
[Result] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                    [sample_id] => 21
                    [sample_type_test_id] => 1
                )
        [1] => Array
            (
                    [sample_id] => 21
                    [sample_type_test_id] => 24
                )
        )
)
```

Then I can simply use `saveAll($this->data['Result'])`

Any hints on how I can improve the form to output the desired array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave a similar answer to another post that might be useful to you, I don't have time to modify it right now, but let me know if this doesn't answer your question then I will elaborate.

[How to create a view page to save two objects in cakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255429/how-to-create-a-view-page-to-save-two-objects-in-cakephp)

ok... after reading your problem further, I think this should do the trick...

```
foreach ($this->data['Result']['sample_type_test_id'] as $v) {
$data = array(
    'id'=>'',
    'sample_id' => $this->data['Result']['sample_id'],
    'sample_type_test_id' => $v
    );
$this->SampleTypeTest->save($data);
}
```

This should save to the db as :

```
id | sample_id | sample_type_test_id
1    21          1
2    21          24
3    21          16
4    21          71
```

Ok try this then...

```
        $data;
    $i=0;
    foreach ($this->data['Result']['sample_type_test_id'] as $v) {
        $data[$i] = array(
            'id'=>'',
            'sample_id' => $this->data['Result']['sample_id'],
            'sample_type_test_id' => $v
            );
        $i++;
    }
    $this->Result->save($data);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Looking at the other answer, I can't quite figure out how to adapt it to this problem. I've basically worked out that for this problem, I need to 're-jig' the array that is posted. So that it sends it to the add action in the way that I can then saveAll() with. Any idea how we could adapt the form 'or' put some kind of foreach loop into the action to process the array into the desired array. Is this the cake way? or am I missing something?

Comment: I feel i do indeed need to use saveAll. I may need to update my question. I think I just need to feed it the correct Array Structure. See saveAll at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

Comment: I have also noticed that you are wrapping your saveAll function in a foreach loop, I have not tested this but is the foreach actually making it to the second index of the array? If one of your actions to a positive save is a redirect... wouldn't that kill the foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah, I've ditched the foreach in the action... Question updated. Hope this is ok.

Comment: can you remove the 
$this->SampleTypeTest->save($data);
and replace it with pr($data);
and paste the output into here?

Comment: I think we're getting closer... The above loop outputs the following array (using debug($data);:

`Array
(
    [sample_id] => 34
    [sample_type_test_id] => 34
)`

So it only saves one record.

Comment: However. Doing a pr($data); reveals 

`Array
(
    [id] => 
    [sample_id] => 34
    [sample_type_test_id] => 41
)

Array
(
    [id] => 
    [sample_id] => 34
    [sample_type_test_id] => 57
)

Array
(
    [id] => 
    [sample_id] => 34
    [sample_type_test_id] => 34
`

Comment: Hmmmm, I think you might have me stumped now... Does the pr() output look like it should work? What are the exact table columns that you have? Maybe remove the 'id' => '' part of the array, I have not tested this, I just assumed that leaving that as a blank string would automatically create a new table row. The output from the db sounds like the entries are overwriting each other each time the save is called.

Comment: better yet... you could modify 
$this->SampleTypeTest->save($data);
to 
if($this->SampleTypeTest->save($data)){
pr('a db entry has been made');
}

then you can count how many times the pr() statement ran.

Comment: Output needs to be as outlined in the second array example in the question. Then I can use saveAll(). Your suggestion is so close. I know it. It outputs `Array(..)Array(..)Array(..)` instead of `[0] => Array(...)[1] => Array(...)[2] => Array(...)` Also, just to clarify. It needs to save to Results not SampleTypeTest i.e. $this->Result->save($data)

Comment: ok... try my edit... Although at the end with the save() i forgot to change it to saveAll().. or do a pr() first.

Comment: sorry forgot to initialize the array... $data = array();

Comment: Ok, It all works now. `if($this->SampleTypeTest->save($data)){ pr('a db entry has been made'); }` seems to have cracked it. Thank you very much indeed Tim.