# How to create a view page to save two objects in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have two models

> Address:firstline,secondline
>   Contact:firstname,lastname

and database tables address and contact respectively. i have to create a view page which should display like below format

first name:
last name:

Address:
First line:
second Line:

NEXT STEP {this button leads to next page}

How to create this view.please explain me with the code
and how to save both the objects in the session after clicking on next step button.and what are the controllers to be written.explain me with the code.

Comment: Here's the relevant manual page: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model (form examples starting under *Working with join model data*). Have you tried some of that?

Answer (score 0):

address_controller.php

```
class AddressController extends AppController {   
 var $uses = array('Address', 'Contact');
```

the above will allow you access to the Contact Model from the Address Controller

then you can save the data from your add function into both tables

```
$addressData = array(
    'id'=>'', 
    'firstline'=>$this->data['Address']['firstline'], 
    'secondline'=>$this->data['Address']['secondline'], 
    'contact_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')
);
```

Then save the data with the following code....

```
$this->Address->save($addressData);
```

I would recommend that you do a check to make sure that the data actually saved and then proceed onto the normal save method for the Contact model.

if you already have the add.ctp created for the Address and Contact Models, then you can just go to your views->address->add.ctp and copy the form fields and paste them into the views->contact->add.ctp form.

without seeing any of your code, it's hard to tell exactly what your fields will be but should look something like this :

```
<input name="data[Contact][firstname]">
<input name="data[Contact][lastname]">
<input name="data[Address][firstline]">
<input name="data[Address][secondline]">
```